# Firefox history & bookmarks don't save, tried everything in the book

Tags: 13.04, firefox, bookmarks

Now, before I begin, I would like to say that I am a fairly advanced user. I know how things work, and I troubleshoot. Therefore as such, I have deleted my profile, recreated it, tested new ones, deleted .mozilla, purged, reinstalled, checked about:config (and changing values which seem to contradict saving history), deleted Firefox and Xmarks, and even manually deleted the folders and remade them.

The .mozilla directory has ALL my user permissions. I made sure of this. Clearing history does NOT generate a new one. History is set to be remembered, and is NOT set to clear when Firefox closes. I have already checked.

If creating a new profile doesn't solve my issue, then how can places.sqlite be the problem (as is suggested over at Mozilla's Mozine/KB)? I've already deleted my Firefox profiles countless times and made countless more new ones, so I hardly doubt it's that now.

Main issue: I open Firefox, I browse, and no history is ever saved when I restart the browser. No bookmarks get saved either, and if I bookmark a page (sometimes before it hasn't even let me), it won't even show up in the bookmarks menu. And it's also worth noting that the history always never saves either.

What does work: Firefox preferences are saved, add-ons, configurations, downloads, extensions, and anything else that isn't explicitly bookmarks or browsing history. Don't know about form history since I don't use that.

I use Firefox 24 on Ubuntu 13.04.

Please help me, I've run out of options and ideas!

Comment: Disable all your add-ons and extension and try again.

Comment: Tried it, didn't work.

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/products/firefox/fix-problems/firefox-wont-save-settings-or-remember-information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably not much of a solution, but I installed Google Chrome, imported everything from Firefox, then nuked everything "Mozilla" related. Then I upgraded to 13.10, nuked Unity, switched to Cinnamon, reinstalled Firefox, imported everything back from Chrome, installed LastPass on BOTH, and now it's all good.

Comment: Look at my answer

Comment: Yes, I read those during my original research on the Mozine/KB, which I stated didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Open your Firefox & go to Help > Troubleshooting Information

There you will have a reset button , that will restores the Firefox to its normal behavior.
[image]

For more information

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/products/firefox/fix-problems/firefox-wont-save-settings-or-remember-information

Comment: That didn't work either.